# How do Gradle dependencies work and how can I import a WooCommerce API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth, jhipster

I am new to using Spring, and I am using Jhipster. In the Backend, I want to make a communication with the WooCommerce API so that with a Spring Batch every hour to check if there are new orders. I found this API: https://github.com/calatonsystems/wc-api-java
The problem is that I still don't understand much of the dependency and import handling. I tried downloading the github repository inside my package where my repositories, services, etc. are. But I run into a lot of import problems, for example, I added the HTTP commons dependency to the build.gradle but I don't know how to run it to inject them. And I feel a bit lost on how to structure this. I simply have to make a query to the API with OAuth 1 (I already tried it with Postman), and my idea is to do it with some service. But I'm a bit lost, mostly with the injection of these dependencies I need, and I would like to know if I'm also downloading the files in that path correctly, or should I download them somewhere else, if I should download the pom.xml, the travis.yml or just the .java files. If any of you also use this API, it would be very helpful. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Their docs  shows how to define maven dependency, so you just need to do the same in gradle by adding `implementation 'com.icoderman:wc-api-java:1.4'` to `dependencies` block in build.gradle. And you don't need to use Spring Batch to retrieve orders every hour, just use `@Scheduled` annotation. I would recommend you learn about gradle, spring and generally about the java ecosystem.

Comment: Thank you very much Gaël. I appreciate your help, I'm going to investigate Spring and Gradle since lately it is a Framework that I'm very interested in. And thank you for telling me about the @Scheduled annotation by the way.